# Good and easy WCF EF4 or XML leaderboard to put into my MVC 3 web app for my WP7 games? Security?

Tags: xml, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, leaderboard

I realized my basic attempt is very hackable. What are the main issues to deal with when creating a leaderboard? Connection string need to be encrypted somehow ? What else? I am hoping it does not get too complex..

Anyone have any good references they have used for doing this  ?

Comment: Isn't a leaderboard just a list of high scores?  As long as it's read-only, how can that be hacked?  What do you mean when you say the basic attempt is very hackable?  In other words, what was your attempt and an example of a hack?

Comment: I mean anyone can see the .xap file and the password/connection string it seems using a basic web service called from a wp7 app.. So trying to figure out what everyone else is doing.. look here for example ...see here http://punkoutersoftware.com/HighScores

Comment: I'm sorry, still confused.  The .xap file you're talking about is a Silverlight file.  The example you're showing me is an MVC app.  MVC is not hackable.  The only people that can see the connection string and password are people that have access to the *server* and the web.config.  As far as silverlight, here are your configuration options: http://www.mohamedibrahim.net/blog/2010/01/27/creating-and-using-silverlight-app-settings-webconfig-configuration-applicatioin-settings-to-change-wcf-service-address-after-deployment-servicereferencesclientconfig-servicereferences-clientconfig/

Comment: I am referring to the ability of anyone being able to see the WSLDL and call that WCF service to create thier own score... Without getting to complicated how can I stop that and make sure they can't easily do that or somehow use the .xap file to get information on how to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem now, based on the comments above.  It may be helpful to rephrase your original question.

Ok, so you can not prevent people from getting the credentials that you use to call your web service from Silverlight or jQuery or any other similar client side code.  To understand this, you have to think about how silverlight works.  Silverlight code is sent to the client.  The client can be anyone, and you do not have control over it except to know that it understands Silverlight code.  So, here is what you *can* accomplish:

1. Obfuscate your code to prevent people from easily copying your presentation logic: http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview
2. Configure your WCF endpoint to use HTTPS to talk to clients.  This will prevent people from easily intercepting communication between these layers.
3. Put all your important code in the WCF service.  This way, if someone decompiles and de-obfuscates your Silverlight code, you don't lose critical code.

This post explains roughly the same thing:

[Does silverlight code need protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244130/does-silverlight-code-need-protection)